# Using mock patch to mock an instance method

Tags: python, mocking

I'm trying to mock something while testing a Django app using the imaginatively named [Mock testing library](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html). I can't seem to quite get it to work, I'm trying to do this:

###### models.py

```py
from somelib import FooClass
    
class Promotion(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(FooClass)
    def bar(self):
        print "Do something I don't want!"
```

###### test.py

```py
class ViewsDoSomething(TestCase):
    view = 'my_app.views.do_something'
    
    def test_enter_promotion(self):
        @patch.object(my_app.models.FooClass, 'bar')
        def fake_bar(self, mock_my_method):
            print "Do something I want!"
            return True
    
        self.client.get(reverse(view))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ```bar``` is in fact an "instance method," and its only parameter is ```self```. To be a class method, it would need to be parameterized with ```cls```, and would be callable as ```Promotion.foo()```.

Comment: Patchable object needs to be quoted like this:

`@patch.object('my_app.models.FooClass', 'bar')`

Comment: @cavaunpeu - not (just) parameterized with `cls`, but more importantly (since `self` and `cls` don't mean anything special in python), decorated with `@classmethod`

Answer (score 103, accepted):

To add onto Kit's answer, specifying a 3rd argument to `patch.object()` allows the mocked object/method to be specified. Otherwise, a default `MagicMock` object is used.

```
    def fake_bar(self):
        print "Do something I want!"
        return True

    @patch.object(my_app.models.FooClass, 'bar', fake_bar)
    def test_enter_promotion(self):
        self.client.get(reverse(view))
        # Do something I want!
```

Note that, if you specify the mocking object as a third argument, then the default `MagicMock()` is **no longer** passed into the patched object -- e.g. no longer:

```
def test_enter_promotion(self, mock_method):
```

but instead:

```
def test_enter_promotion(self):
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object

Comment: I prefer this implementation. It is more clear, especially for beginners in Unit Testing.

Comment: What is the self parameter in this case? Where does it come from?

Comment: @Kesty this must be a method in a Test class. https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#basic-example

Answer (score 45):

Ah I was confused on where to apply that patch decorator. Fixed:

```
class ViewsDoSomething(TestCase):
    view = 'my_app.views.do_something'

    @patch.object(my_app.models.FooClass, 'bar')
    def test_enter_promotion(self, mock_method):
        self.client.get(reverse(view))
```

Comment: Where do you make the connection between the method to mock and the fake implementation now?

Comment: @physicalattraction, the connection is made by the argument `mock_method` passed to the test function. I have been able to use this technique in one of my tests. This is useful when you only want to verify if the mocked method was called.

Comment: @rcode74: How to patch a method of an (some other object) instance inside the testing method. eg: def my_method_to_be_tested(...): r = some_script.some_class(...); r.how_to_patch_this_method.

Comment: @imsrgadich, you would do something like r.how_to_patch_this_method = MagicMock(). You can check MagicMock documentation to see how to assign behavior to the mock object.

Answer (score 7):

If you'd like to do [`assert_called`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called) etc. against the mocked method, use the [`patch.object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object) and wrap replacement method in a `MagicMock(side_effect=)`, ie:

```py
with patch.object(class_to_mock, attribute_name, \
 MagicMock(side_effect=replacement_method)) as replacement_method_mock:
```

eg.:

```py
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock

def fake_bar(self):
    print "Do something I want!"
    return True

def test_enter_promotion(self):
    with patch.object(my_app.models.FooClass, 'bar', MagicMock(side_effect=fake_bar)) as fake_bar_mock:
        self.client.get(reverse(view))
        # Do something I want!
        fake_bar_mock.assert_called()
```