# Testing a user invitation system

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I built a user invitation system in my Flask application and want to test it with Python unittest. I'm using SendGrid to send emails. How can I stop SendGrid from actually sending an email while in a test? I can I receive the user invitation link and pull it into my test? My code is below:

```
# views.py
@app.route('/add_user', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
@groups_required(['site_admin'])
def add_user():
    """
    Send invite email with token to invited user
    """
    form = AddUserForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():

        # token serializer
        ts = URLSafeTimedSerializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])

        email = request.form['email']
        tenant_id = user.custom_data['tenant_id']

        # create token containing email and tenant_id
        token = ts.dumps([email, tenant_id])

        # create url with token, e.g. /add_user_confirm/asdf-asd-fasdf
        confirm_url = url_for(
            'add_user_confirm',
            token=token,
            _external=True)

        try:
            # sendgrid setup
            sg = sendgrid.SendGridClient(
                app.config['SENDGRID_API_KEY'],
                raise_errors=True
            )

            # email setup
            message = sendgrid.Mail(
                to=request.form['email'],
                subject='Account Invitation',
                html='You have been invited to set up an account on PhotogApp. Click here: ' + confirm_url,
                from_email='support@photogapp.com'
            )

            # send email
            status, msg = sg.send(message)

            flash('Invite sent successfully.')
            return render_template('dashboard/add_user_complete.html')

        # catch and display SendGrid errors
        except SendGridClientError as err:
            flash(err.message.get('message'))
        except SendGridServerError as err:
            flash(err.message.get('message'))
    return render_template('dashboard/add_user.html', form=form)


@app.route('/add_user_confirm/<token>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_user_confirm(token):
    """
    Decode invite token and create new user account
    """
    form = RegistrationForm()
    decoded = None
    try:
        ts = URLSafeTimedSerializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        decoded = ts.loads(token, max_age=86400)
        email = decoded[0]
    except:
        abort(404)

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        try:
            tenant_id = decoded[1]

            data = {}
            data['email'] = email
            data['password'] = request.form['password']

            # given_name and surname are required fields
            data['given_name'] = 'Anonymous'
            data['surname'] = 'Anonymous'

            # set tenant id and site_admin status
            data['custom_data'] = {
                'tenant_id': tenant_id,
                'site_admin': 'False'
            }

            # create account
            account = User.create(**data)

            # add user to tenant group
            account.add_group(tenant_id)

            # login user
            login_user(account, remember=True)

            # success redirect
            return render_template('account/add_user_complete.html')
        except StormpathError as err:
            flash(err.message.get('message'))

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        flash("Passwords don't match.")

    return render_template('account/add_user_setpassword.html',
                           form=form,
                           email=email)

# tests.py
def test_add_user(self):
    resp = self.client.post('/add_user', data={
            'email': self.test_email
        }, follow_redirects=True)
assert 'User invitation sent' in resp.data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a pretty perfect case for mocking. The essential idea behind mocking is that you replace the current functionality (in this case, sending an e-mail) with a mundane pass, fail, side-effect.

[If you're using Python 2.7 you'll have to download the mock third party package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock)

Otherwise you can just say

```
from unittest import mock
```

[In this particular case I'd suggest using mock.patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469680/using-mock-patch-to-mock-a-class-method)

```
# tests.py
from unittest import mock

@mock.patch("sg.send") 
def test_add_user(self, mocked_send):
    mocked_send.return_value = None # Do nothing on send
    resp = self.client.post('/add_user', data={
            'email': self.test_email
        }, follow_redirects=True)
assert 'User invitation sent' in resp.data
```

This will make it so that when `sg.send` is called it'll call the mocked function rather than the real function. Since mocks are blank by default no scary e-mail sending.

**NOTE**: `SendGrid` needs to be imported and in scope in your `test.py` file.

Comment: This is great. I've never heard of mock before. I'm trying to get it working but am running into 'ImportError: Here is where I setup 'sg': https://github.com/caseydm/photog/blob/master/project/tests/test_views.py#L63

Comment: I don't have time to look at your code tonight but I'll try to run it tomorrow and report back. If I forget, poke me.

Comment: I ended up asking as a separate question and got a great response. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311001/how-to-mock-a-sendgrid-method-in-python