# How to mock a sendgrid web api v.3 method in python

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, sendgrid

I'm trying to test that a SendGrid method was called without sending an email. When I run my test, the method is not patched and instead runs the original method which sends an email. I'm not sure why my patch is not working. This question is similar to [How to mock a SendGrid method in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311001/how-to-mock-a-sendgrid-method-in-python) but using a different version of SendGrid.

```
# api/Login/utils_test.py
from .utils import send_email
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('api.Login.utils.sg.client.mail.send.post')
def test_send_email(mock_mail_send):
    send_email(email, subject, html)
    assert mock_mail_send.called

# api/Login/utils.py
from api import sg

def send_email(email, subject, html):
    msg = create_email(email, subject, html)
    request_body = msg.get()
    response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=request_body)

# api/__init__.py
from server import sg

# server.py
import sendgrid
import os
sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey=os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
```

Currently when I run `pytest Login/utils_test.py` from inside the api directory, I get an AssertionError:

```
assert False
+  where False = <MagicMock name='post' id='4370000808'>.called
```

I expect the test to pass with no output.

Comment: Can you edit your post to tell us what exactly you're expecting?

Comment: @gkubed edited, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a workaround from the sendgrid-python repo issues https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/issues/293

Going to wrap the call because patch doesn't seem to be working with SendGrid web api v.3 and it doesn't look like they are going to support it.

Updating to the following:

```
# api/utils.py
def send_email(email, subject, html):
    msg = create_email(email, subject, html)
    request_body = msg.get()
    response = _send_email(request_body)
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.body)
    print(response.headers)


def _send_email(request_body):
    """Wrapping the SendGrid mail sending method in order to patch it
    while testing. https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-
    python/issues/293"""
    response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=request_body)
    return response

# api/utils_test.py
@patch('api.Login.utils._send_email')
def test_send_email(mock_mail_send):
    send_email(email, subject, html)
    assert mock_mail_send.called
```

Comment: The link to the github issue is expired. Is there any new link I can refer to?

Answer (score 1):

Not on the Python side, but on the SendGrid side, have you tried using [sandbox mode](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Send/v3_Mail_Send/sandbox_mode.html)?

Comment: i haven't, but i think the problem I'm having is that the method is not being patched. I suspect that it's the way I'm describing the path in the @patch

Comment: The sandbox mode requires an API key with actual production privileges. It's a strange thing to not be able to generate a sandbox only API key.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [Prism](http://stoplight.io/platform/prism) in conjunction with our [Open API definition](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-oai). This will create a local mocked version of the SendGrid API so you can test against any of our endpoints.

Then you can run `prism run --mock --list --spec https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-oai/master/oai_stoplight.json` from your command line.

To have Prism auto-start, please see [this example](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/master/test/test_sendgrid.py#L18).