# Patching a function in a file where it is defined

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to learn unittest patching.  I have a single file that both defines a function, then later uses that function.  When I try to patch this function, its return value is giving me the *real* return value, not the *patched* return value.

How do I patch a function that is both defined and used in the same file?  Note: I did try to follow the advice given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341147/how-to-patch-a-modules-internal-functions-with-mock), but it didn't seem to solve my problem.

**walk_dir.py**

```
    from os.path import dirname, join
    from os import walk
    from json import load


    def get_config():
        current_path =dirname(__file__)
        with open(join(current_path, 'config', 'json', 'folder.json')) as json_file:
            json_data = load(json_file)

        return json_data['parent_dir'] 

    def get_all_folders():
        dir_to_walk = get_config()
        for root, dir, _ in walk(dir_to_walk):
            return [join(root, name) for name in dir]
```

**test_walk_dir.py**

```
    from hello_world.walk_dir import get_all_folders
    from unittest.mock import patch


    @patch('walk_dir.get_config')
    def test_get_all_folders(mock_get_config):
        mock_get_config.return_value = 'C:\\temp\\test\\'
        result = get_all_folders()
        assert set(result) == set('C:\\temp\\test\\test_walk_dir')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try declaring the patch in such way:

```
@patch('hello_world.walk_dir.get_config')
```

As you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14410029/9609843) to the question you linked, it's recommended that your `import` statements match your `patch` statements. In your case `from hello_world.walk_dir import get_all_folders` and `@patch('walk_dir.get_config')` doesn't match.